# While loop for only accepting integer value and exiting on any other input

Tags: c, while-loop

I'm running this program in C to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius and need to accept only integer value from the user.

Please tell me how I can modify this?

```
int main() {
    int x;
    double y;
    while(x>0) {
        printf("Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit:");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        y=((x-32)/1.8)
        printf("%f\n",y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please initialise `x` before you test it (and enable compiler warnings).

Comment: First, the condition of your while loop is using the variable x before it has been assigned a value. Use the return value of `scanf` if you want to check whether it has successfully read an integer

Answer (score 3):

The reason your code does not work is that sometimes `scanf` does not read anything, so it does not modify `x`.

You know that `scanf` read something by checking its return value. It returns the number of "scanned" items. In this case, the number must be `1`.

When `scanf` returns `0` instead, you should read and discard the data in the buffer. You do it by supplying `%*[^\n]` format specifier, which means "read and discard input up to `'\n'`  character. The complete snippet that reads an `int` until success looks like this:

```
while (scanf("%d", &x) != 1) {
    printf("Please enter a valid number:");
    scanf("%*[^\n]");
}
```

**Note:** It goes without saying that you should fix your syntax error with the missing semicolon `;` on the line that computes `y`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the code is working fine as long as I'm entering integer value but goes in infinite loop when I enter something else and hence in while(x>0) i need some expression that'll check if it's integer value and I need to add the code to exit if entered value isn't integer.

Answer (score -1):

- You can use below code.

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  int main()
  {
   int x;
   double y;
   char str1[5];
  int num1,i;
  bool yes = true;
    while(x>0) 
    {
        printf("Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit:");
        scanf("%s",str1);
        for(i=0;str1[i]!='\0';i++)
        if(!(str1[i]>=48&&str1[i]<=56))
        {
           printf("The value is invalid \n");
           yes = false;
        }
        num1 = atoi(str1);

        if(yes == true)
        {
          printf("This Number is %d\n",num1);
          y=((num1-32)/1.8);
          printf("%f\n",y);
         }
     }
  }
  ```

Comment: Code would be clearer, less error prone  (and correct) with `if(!(str1[i]>='0'&&str1[i]<='9'))`.  `str1[i]<=56` is certainly incorrect.

Comment: 1) `int x; ... while(x>0)` replicates OP's failure to initialize `x`. 2) `char str1[5]; ...scanf("%s",str1);` does not properly limit input to 4 characters.